# xargs rm -r with regex returns "no such directory"

Tags: regex, bash, xargs, rm

I have a folder with several subdirectories `b1_3, b1_4` etc. Inside these subdirectories I have some files and other subdirectories, and the names of these subdirs follow a pattern `alpha[digits]_etc`, as such

```
lfppfs@lfppfs:~$ ls -l Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4/b*

Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4/b1_3:
total 364
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:07 alpha0.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.01
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:07 alpha0.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs  1143 ago  4 09:07 alpha0.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:07 alpha10.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.01
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:07 alpha10.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs  1144 ago  4 09:07 alpha10.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs     7 ago  4 09:07 forbiden-sites.in
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs   984 ago  4 09:07 input0alpha0.in
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs   992 ago  4 09:07 input0alpha10.in

Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4/b1_4:
total 364
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:09 alpha0.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.01
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:07 alpha0.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs  1143 ago  4 09:07 alpha0.sh
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:07 alpha10.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.01
drwxr-xr-x 2 lfppfs lfppfs 12288 ago  4 09:07 alpha10.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.1
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs  1144 ago  4 09:07 alpha10.sh
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs     7 ago  4 09:07 forbiden-sites.in
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs   984 ago  4 09:07 input0alpha0.in
-rwxr-xr-x 1 lfppfs lfppfs   992 ago  4 09:07 input0alpha10.in
```

I want to delete only the subdirectories `alpha[digits]_etc` from all directories `b1_[digits]` (please note that there are also files called `alpha[digits].[digits].sh` which I don't want to delete). I've tried my luck with several commands, including

`ls Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4/b* | grep -P "alpha\d*0\.0" | xargs echo rm -r | bash`

But the shell returns

```
rm: cannot remove 'alpha0.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.01': No such file or directory
rm: cannot remove 'alpha0.0_b150_t10000_s5_qmat0.1': No such file or directory
etc
```

Don't know what I'm doing wrong. Hope my question is clear.

**EDIT**

I also tried using `find Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4 -regextype posix-egrep -regex "b\d_\d\/alpha\d*0\.0" -delete` but then the shell returns all files inside `b1_[digits]`, including the ones I don't want to delete.

Comment: Parsing `ls` could be avoided, take a look at: [Why not parse `ls`](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/128985/why-not-parse-ls-and-what-to-do-instead)

Comment: The unix [`find`](https://linux.die.net/man/1/find) should work just fine, use it with `-name` to search for the folders, and use `-exec rm` or `-delete` to delete the returned items

Comment: `find Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4/b1_* -type d -name "alpha_*" -delete`

Comment: The problem is `ls` returns just names without the path, but `rm` needs the path.

Comment: I tried using `find` with the same regex in the question as well but then the regex I use does not work. I cannot use `find` with `-name "alpha_*"` because I have files inside the subdirs `b1_[digits]` called `alpha[digits].sh` which I don't want to delete. They are listed in the `ls` I posted (and I edited the question for clarifying this). @choroba you're right, but I can't work around that as well...

Comment: `find Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4/b1_* -type d -name "alpha_*" -exec rm -r "{}" \;`

Answer (score 0):

As pointed out in the comments by @AdemÖztaş:

```
find ~/Desktop/shape/PD_sigma4/b1_* -regextype posix-egrep -type d -name "alpha[0-9]*" -exec rm -r {} +
```

`-type d` matches only directories and thefore does not match the `alpha[digits].[digits].sh` files. `-delete` action does not remove non-empty directories, that's why I needed `-exec rm -r {} +`